# Cannot install npm modules (packages) in Windows 7?

Tags: node.js, cmd, windows-7, npm, npm-install

I have node js (version 5.6.0) and npm(version 3.6.0) installed on my PC.But the problem is I am not able to install npm packages on my PC.Whenever I run npm install "somepackage" from the Cmd line, it shows "LoadDep:unorm-> get" something like this and installation stops.How can I install Npm packages?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide more info? How is the directory you are running npm, what package are you trying to install?

Comment: @CaioFontes I want to install cordova globally, but if I install anything global or local(in that project) then also nothing is installed.So I dont think its anything specific related to any npm package.

Comment: can you provide the command output ?

Comment: Well, you need to provide more information , so we will be able.to help you

Comment: @mh-cbon, There is no output as such I just get "LoadDep:something", but incidentally I unistalled my node and reinstalled it and it worked.Currently the node version is 4.4.4 and npm version is 2.15.1.Now the package install works.

Comment: @CaioFontes thanks for giving your quality time, but it seems it was the version issue I was stuck in and reinstalling did the trick.Thanks once more :)

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks you too :)